# XML parsing: getting data within tag

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I have been given a task to parse a XML file. 
Sample of XML file

```
<Cards>
  <Card>
    <name> I want `<i>` complete `</i>` text in this `<i>`element`</i>` </name>
  </Card>
</Cards>
```

I have tried using SAX parser as well as DOM parser.

Basically I want complete text between the `<name>` tag including `<i>` tag as output.

In SAX as well as DOM it treats this `<i>` tag as another element as hence I am not getting complete data.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer will depend on the specific language and libraries you are using. Please mention them.

Comment: I am using java and its libraries only to do SAX parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi ritesh if you want treat `<i></i>` as non tags the you have in encode the text data betwwn the tags `<name></name>` into html entities while adding to xml e.g. `&lt;i&gt;` for `<i>`

Comment: Thanks Satya for replying back. It worked. I want to know if I dont want to change it to escape character then can I achieve the same?